# how can i fix this script for deleting bad words in chats

Tags: python, nextcord

```
words_to_filter = ["badword1", "badword2", "badword3"]

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f"on_message event triggered")  # Add this line
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    for word in words_to_filter:
        if word in message.content:
            print(f"Bad word found: {word}") # check on_message event
            await message.delete() #message delete
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, դուք օգտագործել եք արգելված բառ ձեր հաղրոդագրությունում") # after deleting message send message
            return
        else:
            print('Falseee') # if script not working print 'Falseee'
            return
        
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

terminal output:

[image: terminal output]

I tried several options to check if all events are working

the function of the code is to remove bad words in the message
after running the code, when I send any word in the text channel, the on_message event works, but the function itself is not executed

Comment: You're only checking the first word in `words_to_filter`.

Answer (score 1):

The return in for is not needed and letting your code exit once it check the first word in your list as its going into else block

```
words_to_filter = ["badword1", "badword2", "badword3"]

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f"on_message event triggered")
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    for word in words_to_filter:
        if word in message.content:
            print(f"Bad word found: {word}")
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, դուք օգտագործել եք արգելված բառ ձեր հաղրոդագրությունում")
            return

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement inside the loop will terminate the loop after checking the first word.

Your code looks fine, just make one small change.
Remove 'else' and 'return' from below snippet.

```
else:
            print('Falseee') # if script not working print 'Falseee'
            return
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Your code should be like :

```
    print('Falseee') # if script not working print 'Falseee'
    
await bot.process_commands(message)
```